# Definitions lists in semantic

Tags: semantic-ui

We are migrating a site from bootstrap to semantic ui, we've used a lot of horizontal standard definitions lists: dl, dt, dd. Semantic don't style dl's, and recommends using tables for that, we can't afford to use table for this and i would like to know if someone has worked out this.

Thanks
Hans

Comment: Would copying the CSS properties in bootstrap that modify the dl,dt and dd elements to a custom CSS file solve your problem?

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks